# Extract and Copy text between characters in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a way to extract text between 2 characters and copy them to a column at the end of the spreadsheet.

For example, my text looks like [abcdefg], all in Column A,  I am looking to extract the text between the "[" and copy it to a new column at the end of the worksheet (as a new column)

Thanks

Comment: Is the text in **each** cell enclosed in brackets? If so, you can do this without vba, just using `MID` and `LEN` functions.

Comment: the cells have additional text, but certain text between the brackets is what I need extracted. I am hoping to automate the process, why i was hoping to incorporate with vba

Comment: Use instr() to find the position of your brackets, and Mid() to grab the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would resort to functions since they're just the easiest. To pull the data between 2 characters, you'd use a mixture of `MID` and `FIND` functions.

So, assuming your data was in cell `A1`, you could put this formula in the cell where you want the parsed value:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1)
```

If you wanted to automate it, you could put it into a macro then copy / paste-special values to remove the function and keep the values.

Comment: This works, and i should have stated this but the text has spaces in the brackets so [ adfhalkdhflkdhf ], although this extracts it I would need to do a trim; is it possible to do all of this in one vba script?

Comment: Well, either add in a `TRIM` - `=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1))`; OR just add the space to your formula `=MID(A1,FIND("[ ",A1)+2,FIND(" ]",A1)-FIND("[ ",A1)-2)`, but I still don't see much need for VBA here.

Comment: VBA isn't needed, i agree with you there. we have these documents come through quite a bit, so hoping to automate the process with the push of a button, instead of pasting formulas.

Comment: Again, as I said in the solution - I agree with automating the formula / putting it in, just not using VBA for doing the calculation itself.... Excel can do it natively.

Comment: gotcha! will go this route for sure! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write this into a vba module, looping through all entries in the A column and extracting the text inside the [] into an entry in column B, it might look something like:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim i as integer
Dim lastRow as Integer
Dim brack1pos as Integer
Dim brack2pos as Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Sheet Name")

for i = 1 to lastRow  'I'll leave to you how to find the last row
     brack1pos = InStr(ws.Range("A" & i), "[")
     brack2pos = InStr(ws.Range("A" & i), "]")
     ws.Range("B" & i) = Trim(Mid(ws.Range("A" & i), brack1pos + 1, brack2pos - brack1pos - 1))
next
```

Comment: Made a couple edits after testing in a simple vba module.  This method does work.

Comment: Hmm, i couldn't get this to extract the data, I used column Z, but in reality would need to format the code to use the next open column at the end of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah, woops.  Missed the bit about the additional text.

Comment: yeah so each cell looks like [ ABCDEFG ] additional text here

Comment: you'll need to search out the open column and the last row of the worksheet, but this should give you the basic structure for looping through and extracting the string between the brackets.

Comment: I'm new, so I am not sure how to do this. I will learn with time I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

This is for text in Cell 1, 1 but you can toss some variables in there as you loop through your rows.  It will grab the values within square brackets & trim it, additional text can be in front or behind the brackets.

```
    Dim iPos1 As Integer
    Dim iPos2 As Integer
    iPos1 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), "[")
    iPos2 = InStr(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), "]")

    Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = Trim(Mid(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), iPos1 + 1, iPos2 - iPos1 - 1))
```

Comment: I get an "invalid procedure call or argument" error for this line Sheet1.Cells(1, 2) = Trim(Mid(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), iPos1 + 1, iPos2 - iPos1 - 1))

Comment: It's looking for your string in Cell(1,1).. A1.  It will drop the result in cell(1,2) A2.  Explicitly on Sheet1. You can change those to whatever you want.

Comment: Gotcha. I am starting with A3 so (1,3) and putting result in Z3 (26,3).....I edited the script to match. but get same error; sorry i am a newb at this.

Comment: Sorry, mis-typed.  Cell(Row, Column)  I ment Cell(1,2) is B2

Comment: That worked! How do i apply this to all rows in column A?